# find does not find directory

Tags: directory, find

I have a folder with information of the courses I am teaching or I have teached. In there I execute `find` to search by name:

```
~/Academic/Cursos$ find . -name '2022*' -print
./MaGAAV/Formulación de proyectos educativos IV/2022A
./MaGAAV/Gestión de entornos tecnológicos abiertos/2022A
./LiDSW/Principios de diseño web/2022A
./LiDSW/Principios de diseño web/2022B
./DSAE/SeminarioDeEspecialidad/2022A
~/Academic/Cursos$
```

If I move into a sub-folder that does not appear in the results of `find`:

```
~/Academic/Cursos$ cd MaGC/
~/Academic/Cursos/MaGC$ find . -name '2022*' -print
~/Academic/Cursos/MaGC$
```

Yet if I go one step further:

```
~/Academic/Cursos/MaGC$ cd Gestión\ de\ sistemas\ de\ información\ cultural
~/Academic/Cursos/MaGC/Gestión de sistemas de información cultural$ find . -name '2022*' -print
./2022A
~/Academic/Cursos/MaGC/Gestión de sistemas de información cultural$
```

So, the question is, why is that `find` does not find that folder when called two steps above? It does not seem to be because of the non ASCII characters nor the spaces, as they are present in other folders that do appear in the original results.

Comment: Usually, "weird" behavior like this is because of how `find` treats symbolic links - see for example [find /bin -iname 'sh*' doesn't return any result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374959/find-bin-iname-sh-doesnt-return-any-result)